# AMD processor families and models

Tags: performance, cpu, operating-systems, monitoring

I want to use hardware performance monitors on my [AMD Opteron 6376](http://products.amd.com/en-us/OpteronCPUDetail.aspx?id=817&f1=&f2=&f3=Yes&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&) processor.

Unfortunately, AMD has many manuals and I can't figure out which one I need from this (partial) list:

- http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/49125_15h_Models_30h-3Fh_BKDG.pdf
- http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/42300_15h_Mod_10h-1Fh_BKDG.pdf
- http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/52740_16h_Models_30h-3Fh_BKDG.pdf

How do I know the correct family (15h or 16h) and the correct family (10h-1Fh or 30h-3Fh)?

All docs can be found [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/tech-docs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server: NT4/2000/2003/2003R2/2008/2008R2/2012

WS:     95/98/NT4/2000/XP/Vista/7/8/8.1

```
wmic cpu get * /format:list | more
```

GUI: [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)

[image: CPU-Z]

linux:

- ```
  $ less /proc/cpuinfo
  ```
- ```
  $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
  ```
- ```
  # dmidecode --type processor
  ```

Ubuntu:

- ```
  $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
  ```
- ```
  $ lscpu
  ```
- ```
  $ sudo lshw -class processor
  ```
- ```
  $ sudo dmidecode -t 4
  ```
- ```
  $ cpuid
  ```

install cpuid:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cpuid
```

install i-Nex – CPU-Z for Linux:

- ```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:i-nex-development-team/stable
  ```
- ```
  $ sudo apt-get update
  ```
- ```
  $ sudo apt-get install i-nex
  ```

[image: i-Nex – CPU-Z for Linux]

Unlocking Root Account in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

Mac OS X:

```
sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu
```

[AMD Opteron 6376 processor SPEC® CFP2006 Result](http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2012q4/cpu2006-20121005-24692.html)

Comment: What is wmic? and how can I get it?

Comment: What you OS version?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: @Simple.guy update, add OS tag at you question)